# Dynamically Splitting and naming the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame called "loan", this contains all information like customer ID, loan amount, term of loan etc.

There is a column called "yq" which is basically the year and quarter of the loan disbursement date

```
    ID      yq
    1       2014 Q4
    2       2014 Q4
    3       2015 Q1
    4       2015 Q2
    5       2015 Q3
```

I wanted to split the data frame based on the quarters and year, so naturally I used the following:

```
 list_of_dataframes <- split(loan,                  
                       with(loan, yq), 
                       drop = TRUE)
```

But this leads to me hard coding the split datasets like so:

```
      loan_2014_q4 <- list_of_dataframes[[1]]

      loan_2015_q1 <- list_of_dataframes[[2]]
```

Is there a way to do this better, like where the name of the dataframe is "loan" followed by the value in the row for each. Also the number of dataframes to be saved is dynamic

Basically I am trying to automate the process, thus the number of split and data frame are automatically split, named and saved.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would ultimately recommend you keep your data in a `list` (or you don't even need lists if you are using tools like "data.table" and "dplyr" which give you extremely flexible subsetting options).

However, if you really feel you need separate `data.frame`s, try the following:

```
## Assume your data.frame is called "mydf"....
temp <- split(mydf, mydf$yq, drop = TRUE)
ls()
[1] "mydf" "temp"
temp
# $`2014 Q4`
#   ID      yq
# 1  1 2014 Q4
# 2  2 2014 Q4
# 
# $`2015 Q1`
#   ID      yq
# 3  3 2015 Q1
# 
# $`2015 Q2`
#   ID      yq
# 4  4 2015 Q2
# 
# $`2015 Q3`
#   ID      yq
# 5  5 2015 Q3
```

Now, use `list2env` to put each list item into the global environment as its own object. Modify the list's names first.

```
list2env(setNames(temp, sprintf("loan_%s", gsub("\\s+", "_", names(temp)))), .GlobalEnv)
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
ls()
# [1] "loan_2014_Q4" "loan_2015_Q1" "loan_2015_Q2" "loan_2015_Q3" "mydf" "temp"
loan_2014_Q4
#   ID      yq
# 1  1 2014 Q4
# 2  2 2014 Q4
```

Comment: @ Ananda Mahto, very very elegant solution thanks, vdep's solution mapped the name and the file incorrectely.                                                                                                        I had a quick question, I am exporting the split dataset to to Mysql server, How can i make this dynamic too?                                                                                             Right now this is what I doing                                   dbWriteTable(connection1, value = `loan_2015 Q4`, name = "loan_2015_Q4", overwrite= T)

Comment: @user3875610, sorry, no experience with that part of your question.... How do you normally export the dataset to MySQL server?

Comment: @user3875610, sorry--just saw your edited comment. Perhaps you can try using `lapply` over the names of your split dataset. Generally, `list`s are easier to deal with than a whole bunch of separate objects in your workspace.

Comment: @ Ananda Mahto, thanks for all your help. I will look into the lapply.   Normal export is as i mentioned in the previous comment

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked to automate, run the following after creating `list_of_dataframes`

```
temp <- unique(loan$yq)
for(i in 1:length(list_of_dataframes)) {
    assign(paste0("loan_",temp[i]),list_of_dataframes[[i]])
}
```

Comment: perfect solution, quick question, the above solution is dynamic in every way right?

Comment: It does the job irrespective of number of sub data frames `list_of_dataframes` has and its names. If this is what you meant by dynamic then,yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I needed